# select2 created on flow is not accessible

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I try to clone container on click and append after last element. The cloned container holds select2 drop boxes. My problem is that I can not select in the new appended containers

Fiddler
http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/ypp33/1/

piece of code what I'm trying

```
jQuery('div.wizard-card').on('click', 'button.add_more', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (countContainers() == true) {
                jQuery(this).closest('button').prop('disabled', true);
            }

            jQuery('.uni_choice:last').clone().insertAfter('.uni_choice:last');
            jQuery('.uni_choice').prev().find('button.add_more').replaceWith('<button class="delete btn btn-file"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clone a select2 element is not possible to use a deep jQuery clone.

The only way I found is to destroy the current instance of the plugin and then recreate all.

Ref:

> destroy
>
> Reverts changes to DOM done by Select2. Any selection done via Select2
>   will be preserved.

Code:

```
 jQuery('div.wizard-card').on('click', 'button.add_more', function (e) {

     $('select.locations, select.grade').each(function (key, value) {
         $(this).select2("destroy");
     });

     e.preventDefault();
     if (countContainers() == true) {
         jQuery(this).closest('button').prop('disabled', true);
     }

     jQuery('.uni_choice:last').clone().insertAfter('.uni_choice:last');
     jQuery(this).closest('button.add_more').replaceWith('<button class="delete btn btn-file"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>');

     jQuery('select.locations').select2({
         placeholder: 'Alle Städte',
         allowClear: true
     })

     jQuery('select.grade').select2({
         placeholder: 'Alle Abschlusse',
         allowClear: true
     })

 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dC463/

Comment: Thank you very much !! Destroying and recreating select2 works

Answer (score 0):

To clone the event you need to add true parameter to the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)and provide separate id

```
jQuery('.uni_choice:last').clone(true).attr('id', 'sample')
```

You can check the http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/ypp33/3/

As of now it will fire events on parents because you are binding custom events to it using jquery. You need to analyze that

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I've been taking a look on it but I'm not sure if this would be a workaround in my case.

Comment: try changing common classes and id like grade select2-offscreen because they can cause issue.